# The limit of the ratios of terms from a converging and a diverging series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a **decreasing** sequence such that $\sum_1^{\infty} a_n < \infty$

Suppose $(b_n)$ is a **decreasing** sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum_1^{\infty}b_n = \infty$.

Is it true that $\lim_n \frac{a_n}{b_n} =0$?

I've been trying to prove this but I've failed. I think that it is plausible because it is certainly true whenever $b_n$ is asymptotically larger than or equal to $\frac{1}{n}$ , i.e, it is a well-known fact that $na_n \to 0$.

Here is a counterexample when $a_n$ is not decreasing:

let $a_n=\left\{
     \begin{array}{}
       \frac{1}{n} & \text{if } n \text{ is a power of 2}\\
       0 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Let $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then clearly, $\limsup_n \frac{a_n}{b_n} =1$, so the claim fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question did not specify that the sequence $(b_n)$ is decreasing. There is then a simple counterexample: Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$, and let $b_n=1$ when $n$ is odd and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ when $n$ is even.

We now show how to  construct a counterexample for the modified problem where the sequence $(b_n)$ is also decreasing.  More precisely, we produce **non-increasing** sequences $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ that do the job. One can perturb these by an extremely quickly decreasing sequence if we want *strictly* decreasing sequences.

Let $(F_n)$ be a **very** rapidly increasing sequence of positive integers. For concreteness and fun, let $F_n=2^{2^{n-1}}+1$, but we could use the slower growing $F_n=(n!)^2$.

For the $b_i$, use $F_1$ copies of $\frac{1}{F_1}$, followed by $F_2$ copies of $\frac{1}{F_2}$, followed by $F_3$ copies of $\frac{1}{F_3}$, and so on. The divergence of $\sum b_i$ is clear.

We now describe the $a_i$. Let $n_1=1$ be the index of the first occurrence  of $\frac{1}{F_1}$ in the sequence $(b_n)$. Let $n_2$ be the index of the first occurrence of $\frac{1}{F_2}$. Define $n_3$, $n_4$, and so on analogously.

Let $a_1=\frac{1}{F_1}$. For $i=n_1+1$ to $n_2$, let $a_i=\frac{1}{F_2}$. For $i=n_2+1$ to $n_3$, let $a_i=\frac{1}{F_3}$, and so on. Note that $a_i=b_i$ at $i=n_1,n_2,\dots$, ensuring that $\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ does not have limit $0$.

Finally we show that $\sum a_i$ converges. This is because for $k\ge 2$ the sequence $(a_n)$ has only $F_{k-1}$ copies of $\frac{1}{F_k}$, and $\sum \frac{F_{k-1}}{F_{k}}$ converges.

Comment: Nice! I didn't think it was true, but this is convincing.